# Can I call a mdoc macro inline?

Tags: groff

Despite the many conveniences of `mdoc`, I find syntax of troff is still a bit too newline-rich or "spaghetti" compared to the other languages. Consider this example:

```
.Sh DESCRIPTION
The
.Nm
utility extracts C interface descriptions from a header file composed
using the SQLite documentation syntax (see
.Sx SYNTAX ) .
It then emits the corresponding set of
.Xr mdoc 7
manpages, one per interface description.
By default,
.Nm
reads from standard input and outputs files into the current directory.
Its arguments are as follows:
```

All these lines for a paragraph starting a list is quite odd to me.  Is there a way to call macros inline?

---

What I have tried involves using the strings syntax to invoke the macros, as groff's manual states that strings, diversions, and macros are stored in a shared namespace. This does get me somewhere, but the `.if` conditions on [at the start of the macros](https://github.com/unofficial-mirror/groff/blob/master/tmac/doc.tmac-u) end up not processed and spit out raw.

```
.Sh DESCRIPTION
The \*[Nm] utility extracts C interface descriptions from a header file composed
using the SQLite documentation syntax (see \*[Sx SYNTAX]).
It then emits the corresponding set of \*[Xr mdoc 7] manpages, one per interface
description. By default, \*[Nm] reads from standard input and outputs files into
the current directory.
Its arguments are as follows:
```

I then tried to add another string definition to insert a newline. `.ds n \!` didn't quite work, and what I ended up having was a diversion:

```
.box n
\!
.box

.Sh DESCRIPTION
The \*n\*[Nm] utility extracts C interface descriptions... (see \*n\*[Sx SYNTAX]).
It then...
```

Now the `.if` spam is gone, but unfortunately I get a stray, actual newline in the output. Is there a more perfect way to call these macros? (We will think about mandoc compatibility later.)

Addendum:

- With the "see SYNTAX" bit added, it appears that the newline is somehow inherent to the `.Nm` macro, as the `.Sx` one only produces a stray trailing space. Still, can we get rid of both?
- If I remove the space after `\*n\*[Nm]`, the extra newline is gone, but that looks... odd in the source. The `SYNTAX` one is improved by calling `\n*[Sx Syntax ) .]` like in the original, but it somehow produces a paragraph break too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a `sed` script to do this.

E.g., for `eqn`, I have a script, `myeqn`, to convert `.EA` into `.EN\n.EQ`:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/^\. *EA\(.*\)$/.EN\n.EQ \1/g
```

Then I run this:

```
myeqn < file.ms | groff -e -ms > main.ps
```

You can automate this with Makefiles if needed.

P.S. The newlines in Groff take getting used to, but you start to appreciate them after a while.